# Sustainsys.Saml2.Exceptions.InvalidSignatureException

Tags: sustainsys-saml2

In my callback GetExternalLoginAsync, the return value is always null.  So I added ILogger into the SP Options and was able to see the Sustainsys.Saml2.Exceptions.InvalidSignatureException: The signing algorithm http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256 is weaker than the minimum accepted http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1. If you want to allow this signing algorithm, use the minIncomingSigningAlgorithm configuration attribute. being thrown.

I followed the suggestion to add the minIncomingSigningAlgorithm="SHA256" however now i'm getting a yellow screen error.

The problem is happening on a Windows 2008 R2 server.  It worked fine on all of our other servers so I'm assuming it has something to do with the OS.

I have recently installed .NET 4.6.1 into this box.

```
        var loginInfo = await HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(); //always null
```

Answer (score 0):

The windows server seems to be incompatible with SHA-256.
Tried SHA-16 on the certificate and it worked.
I am by no means suggesting to use SHA-16 given that this is a very insecure cryptographic method and should not be used, but I'm just highlighting what worked with our very old operating system.